# How to delay effect of "include" directive in Makefile.am until make (avoid "include" being seen by Automake)?

Tags: automake

My `Makefile.am` includes a file (with various defined variables), for example:

```
include make.config

...
```

The problem is that this file is in turn generated by a tool (i.e. `config.generator.sh`) based on some input file (i.e. `input.dat`). The straightforward and **wrong** idea would be to add a rule to generate `make.config`:

```
make.config : input.dat
    config.generator.sh input.dat > make.config

include make.config

...
```

Although this content is perfectly working makefile on its own without `automake`, the idea is doomed with `automake`. The `make.config` file is included by `automake` before I even have a chance to execute `make` (and it fails as the file is not yet generated):

```
automake: cannot open < make.config: No such file or directory
```

**Is there a way to postpone effect of `include` directive until `make` is run (possibly by using another directive)?**

There is probably a way to simply run arbitrary commands before any makefile generation is done (i.e. [`AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS*`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Configuration-Commands.html)). But the question is more complicated because the `config.generator.sh` is supposed to use executables which are in turn also generated during the same build process (so there is a dependency chain which logically has to be managed by makefiles from the same project). [The documentation simply confirms the logic without providing alternatives](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Include.html).

Comment: The solution is described in [this email](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2002-01/msg00155.html) of Automake's mailing list.

Comment: Post that as an answer to your question and accept it. That way you get the self-learner badge, the question will show up as answered and I think you get a bit of reputation for it, too.

Comment: @JackKelly , thanks! I didn't expect site allows me to answer my own qustions.

Comment: Actually, there is an exception to this behavior. It probably makes sense, but it's still confusing. In our app Makefile.am we have something like: 

include $(EXTERNAL_LIB_LOCATION)/some.mk

This won't be expanded by automake, since it doesn't know what EXTERNAL_LIB_LOCATION is -  the variable gets defined when make is called. In this case, the include directive is carried as-is to the generated Makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is described in [**this email**](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2002-01/msg00155.html) of Automake's mailing list.

The idea is to use `include` directives inside small regular "wrapper" `makefile` and include Automake-generated `Makefile` into it (note the upper case `M`). Because `makefile` is not an Automake template, the `include` works as expected triggering builds for non-existing files.

Note that:

- By default `make` utility will search for `makefile` first (not for `Makefile`) making this approach working seamlessly.
- It is still recommended to specify all rules inside `Makefile.am` and keep the "wrapper" `makefile` simple. The rules for non-existing files will naturally come from the generated `Makefile` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I've come across the same annoying problem today when moving my OCaml project to Autotools. My solution is to use `autoconf`'s substitution to go around `automake`. For the above example, I'd add a substitution to `configure.ac`:

```
AC_SUBST([include_make_config], ["include make.config"])
```

and adjust `Makefile.am`, replacing the `include` directive with the `autoconf` variable reference:

```
make.config : input.dat
    config.generator.sh input.dat > make.config

@include_make_config@
...
```

`automake` doesn't touch the `@include_make_config@` line so it gets carried over into the generated `Makefile.in`. When `autoconf` takes over, it substitutes the variable with `include  make.config` in the final `Makefile`.

*Note: I use this with OCaml's `ocamldep` dependency generator.*